# what's the difference between eks-cluster-sg-my-cluster-uniqueID, ControlPlaneSecurityGroup and ClusterSharedNodeSecurityGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-security-group

I'm learning Security groups for Pods.
[security-groups-for-pods.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/security-groups-for-pods.html)

The doc mentioned.

> They must allow inbound communication from the security group applied to your nodes (for kubelet) over any ports that you've configured probes for.

> They must allow outbound communication over TCP and UDP ports 53 to a security group assigned to the Pods (or nodes that the Pods run on) running CoreDNS. The security group for your CoreDNS Pods must allow inbound TCP and UDP port 53 traffic from the security group that you specify.

So, as I know the `kubelet` and `CoreDNS` are on Worker node

But now I'm confused which one is worker node security group that I should configure.

And what's the difference between  eks-cluster-sg-my-cluster-uniqueID, ControlPlaneSecurityGroup and ClusterSharedNodeSecurityGroup?

I had read the document [EKS security group requirements and considerations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/sec-group-reqs.html),
but it looks like it only mentioned eks-cluster-sg-my-cluster-uniqueID this security group.

And not sure about other 2, and which one is the worker node group?

Thanks in advance if anyone can help!